# Remove items from one list based on the contents of another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am trying to remove all entities in one list from another.

One of the lists is a **list of lists.**

Whilst another is a **list of tuples**.

```
ScoutNameList = [[('Rory', 'Adair')], [('Fiona', 'Adair')]]
ScoutNamedFromPatrol = [('Rory', 'Adair'), ('Fiona', 'Adair'), ('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
ScoutNamedFromPatrol.remove(ScoutNameList)
```

**Expected Result**

```
ScoutNamedFromPatrol=[('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
```

**Actual Result**

```
ScoutNamed=[('Rory', 'Adair'), ('Fiona', 'Adair'), ('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. However, note that you have to flatten `ScoutNameList`, you can do that with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
[i for i in ScoutNamedFromPatrol if i not in chain(*ScoutNameList)]
#[('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
```

Where:

```
list(chain(*ScoutNameList))
#[('Rory', 'Adair'), ('Fiona', 'Adair')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for l in ScoutNameList:
    ScoutNamedFromPatrol.remove(l[0])
>>> ScoutNamedFromPatrol
[('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions -

```
ScoutNamedFromPatrol = [s for s in ScoutNamedFromPatrol if [s] not in ScoutNameList]
```

Comment: Missed `[]` in the answer - try it now

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important, you can use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) or its syntactic sugar `-`. Since `ScoutNameList` is nested, with each sublist containing a single item, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to construct an iterable of scalars.

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = list(set(ScoutNamedFromPatrol) - set(map(itemgetter(0), ScoutNameList)))
# [('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
```

A less [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) alternative suggested by @TrebuchetMS:

```
res = list(set(ScoutNamedFromPatrol) - set(x[0] for x in ScoutNameList))
```

A more adaptable version can deal with multiple items in *inner* lists of `ScoutNameList`:

```
from itertools import chain
res = list(set(ScoutNamedFromPatrol) - set(chain.from_iterable(ScoutNameList)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ScoutNameList = [[('Rory', 'Adair')], [('Fiona', 'Adair')]]
ScoutNamedFromPatrol = [('Rory', 'Adair'), ('Fiona', 'Adair'), ('Ruariri', 'OBrien')]
for x in ScoutNameList:
    for y in x:
        if y in ScoutNamedFromPatrol:

            ScoutNamedFromPatrol.remove(y)

print(ScoutNamedFromPatrol)
```